# TO everyone or FOR everyone in the following context?

Tags: prepositions

What's of the following sentence sounds more native & correct?

> "There is nothing like beautiful & warm words **for/ to** anyone anywhere,
>   especially **for/to** the worker in his work."

Answer (score 1):

> There is *nothing* like beautiful & warm words **for** anyone anywhere, especially **for** the worker in his work.

First, you don't normally use *no nothing*. Maybe only for very informal emphasis. Otherwise *nothing* says it all.

Then I would use *for* as it is an offering of sorts. Maybe you mean  [***for***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/for):

> 4) in honor of"   ⇒ *to give a banquet for someone*"